# List Response Group agent participation from csv file

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-to-csv

I`m trying to import a csv list of skype for business on-prem users and to run the

"Get-CsRgsAgentGroup | Where {$_.AgentsByUri -Like “*risual.user*” | FT Name"
command for each user in the csv file, using a foreach loop, however it simply doesn`t work.

Can somebody let me know where I`m mistaken?

```
$users = import-csv -Path  "C:\Users\<MY_USER>\Desktop\Users.csv" -Delimiter '~'

foreach ($user in $users)
{
 

get-csrgsagentgroup | Where-Object {$_.AgentsByUri -like "$user"} | Select name

}
```

Comment: CSV files usually have _columns_, so `$user` would refer to a row with one or more column values. How many columns do you have in your CSV file?

Comment: Just one column called "user" with 5 rows for each user (It`s a test and the plan is to have big amount of users, let`s say 200)

Comment: Then the filter should be `{$_.AgentsByUri -like $user.user}`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn`t work out.. I also ran the script from skype for business powershell, so the skype for business modules could be included.

Comment: If finally worked... See the edit below:

$users = import-csv -Path  "C:\Users\<MY_USER>\Desktop\Users.csv" -Delimiter '~'

foreach ($user in $users)
{
 $user=$user.User
 $csuser= 'sip:'+$user
get-csrgsagentgroup | Where-Object {$_.AgentsByUri -like "$csuser"} | Select name

}

I forgot that S4B needs "sip:" so it could identify the enabled S4B users..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd strongly suggest you post an answer below! :)

Answer (score 0):

If finally worked... See the edit below:

```
$users = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\<MY_USER>\Desktop\Users.csv" -Delimiter '~'
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user=$user.User $csuser= 'sip:'+$user get-csrgsagentgroup | Where-Object {$_.AgentsByUri -like "$csuser"} | Select name
}
```

I forgot that S4B needs "sip:" so it could identify the enabled S4B users